# How to read and concatenate strings repeatedly in C

Tags: c

The program needs to do the following：

1. initialise the combined string variable.
2. read a string (input1)  of no more than 256 characters then:
   Until the first character of the read string is '#'
3. allocate enough space for a new combined string variable to hold the current combined string variable and the new read-string (input1).
4. then copy the contents of the old combined variable to the new, bigger, combined variable string.
5. then concatenate the newly read-string (input1)  to the end of the new combined string.
6. deallocate the old combined string.
7. read a string into input 1 again.
8. After the user has typed a string with '#' print out the new combined string.

test input: where I am #here

expected output: whereIam

actually output: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Note that the spaces above separate the strings. Write two more test cases.

And that is my own code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> // for malloc
#include<string.h> // for string funs

int main(void) {
    char input1[257];
    printf("Please enter a string here: ");
    scanf("%256s",input1);
    int input1_index = 0;
    while (input1[input1_index] != '#') {
        input1_index++;
    }
    char *combined;
    combined = malloc(sizeof(char)*(input1_index+1+1));
    combined[0] = '\0';
    strcpy(combined,input1);

    printf("%s\n",combined);


    return 0;
}
```

How to modify my code? What is the Segmentation fault (core dumped)?
Thank you all.

Comment: You are allocating space for the shortened string yet you try to copy the full string. Results in buffer overflow. Change: `strcpy(combined,input1);` -> `strncpy(combined,input1,input1_index); combined[input1_index] = 0;`

Comment: You are still copying the entire input string, which is bigger than what you allocated. You can replace the '#' with '\0'.

Comment: @kaylum I try to do that, but it still have error. Test input: string here #st, output: string

Comment: Then do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger. Have a look at the `input1` value. Is it what you expect? Trace the `while` loop. Does it stop when you expect it to? When code doesn't work the next step is to debug it. Also, think about what happens if the input does not contain `#`.

Comment: Your requirements seem to lead one in a way that is not necessarily optimal. I doubt that all that copying is necessary. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Neil The instructions are fine; solutions to basic homework need not be optimal. The point of the exercise is clearly to further an understanding of handling strings and memory, which should include fundamentals like `strcpy` and `strcat`, and does cover a decent range of functionality (6+ library calls to learn). If the basics are not learned, how can one know when to optimize? Costantino's answer below is an example: only in understanding how `malloc` + `strcpy` + `strcat` works does opting for optimizations like `realloc` + `strcpy(dest + old_size, source)` start to make sense.

Comment: @Oka Good point; I guess I just didn't really understand about how '#' fits into it. Your answer is clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

With [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), the specifier `%Ns` consumes and discards all leading whitespace before reading non-whitespace characters - stopping when trailing whitespace is encountered or `N` non-whitespace characters are read.

With the input

```
where I am #here
```

this

```
char input1[257];
scanf("%256s", input1);
```

will result in the `input1` buffer containing the string `"where"`.

This `while` loop

```
while (input1[input1_index] != '#') {
    input1_index++;
}
```

does not handle the specified *"[read strings...] Until the first character of the read string is '#'"*. It simply searches the one string you have read for the `'#'` character, and can easily exceed the valid indices of the string if one does not exist (as in the case of `"where"`). This will lead to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), and is surely the cause of your SIGSEGV.

---

Your code does not follow the instructions detailed.

A loop is required to read two or more whitespace delimited strings using `scanf` and `%s`. This loop should end when `scanf` fails, or the the first character of the read string is `'#'`.

Inside this loop you should get the string length of the read string (`strlen`) and add that to the *existing string* length. You should allocate a *new buffer* of this length plus one (`malloc`), and exit the loop if this allocation fails.

- You should then copy the existing string to this new buffer (`strcpy`).
- You should then concatenate the read string to this new buffer (`strcat`).
- You should then deallocate the existing string buffer (`free`).
- You should then copy the *pointer value* of the new string buffer to the existing string buffer variable (`=`).

Then repeat the loop.

In pseudocode, this roughly looks like:

```
input := static [257]
combined := allocate [1] as ""
size := 0

exit program if combined is null

print "Enter strings: "

while read input does not begin with '#' do
    add length of input to size

    temporary := allocate [size + 1]

    stop loop if temporary is null

    copy combined to temporary
    concatenate input to temporary

    deallocate combined
    combined := temporary
end

print combined
deallocate combined
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have already explained what you should do. But my additional suggestion is to take those detailed instructions and make them comments. Then for each one of them translate into C code:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    // initialise the combined string variable.
    char *combined = malloc(1);
    combined[0] = 0;
    while (true) {
        // read a string (input1) of no more than 256 characters 
        char input1[257];
        if (scanf("%256s", input1) != 1) {
            break;
        }
        // then: Until the first character of the read string is '#'
        if (input1[0] == '#') {
            break;
        }
        // allocate enough space for a new combined string variable to hold the current combined string variable and the new read-string (input1).
        char *tmp = malloc(strlen(combined) + strlen(input1) + 1);
        // then copy the contents of the old combined variable to the new, bigger, combined variable string.
        strcpy(tmp, combined);
        // then concatenate the newly read-string (input1) to the end of the new combined string.
        strcat(tmp, input1);
        // deallocate the old combined string.
        free(combined);
        combined = tmp; // <-- My interpretation of what the aim is
        // read a string into input 1 again. <-- I guess they mean to loop
    }
    // After the user has typed a string with '#' print out the new combined string.
    printf("%s", combined);
    free(combined);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice how "initialize", means "make it a proper C string which can be extended later".

When you read anything remember to check if the read was successful.

The first character of `input1` is just `input1[0]'. It's always safe to check it (if the read was successful), because it must be the first character or the string terminator. No risk of false detection.

Allocation requires to add the size of `combined`, `input1`, and the string terminator.

Copy and concatenation are available in `<string.h>`.

Notice that the instructions are missing a line stating that the new combined string should become the current combined string, but it's pretty obvious from the intent.

I strongly dislike the suggested (implied) implementation which calls for a sequence  such as:

```c
read
while (check) {
    do_stuff
    read
}
```

My preference goes to the non repeated read:

```c
while (true) {
    read
    if (!check) break;
    do_stuff
}
```

Finally, free your memory. Always. Don't be lazy!

Just for completeness, another option is to store the size of your combined string, to avoid calling `strlen` on something you already know. You could also leverage the `calloc` and `realloc` functions, which have been available since a lot of time:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t capacity = 1;
    char *combined = calloc(capacity, 1);
    while (true) {
        char input1[257];
        if (scanf("%256s", input1) != 1 || input1[0] == '#') {
            break;
        }
        capacity += strlen(input1);
        combined = realloc(combined, capacity);
        strcat(combined, input1);
    }
    printf("%s", combined);
    free(combined);
    return 0;
}
```

Finally for the additional test strings:

```
these are not the droids you're looking for #dummy
a# b## c### d#### e##### #f###### u#######(explicit)
```

## Useless addition

You could also limit the number of reallocations by using a `size`/`capacity` couple  and doubling the capacity each time you need more. Also (not particularly useful here) checking the return value of memory allocation function is a must. My checking for `realloc` is needlessly complicated here, because memory is freed at program termination, but, nevertheless, free your memory. Always. Don't be lazy!

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t capacity = 257, size = 0;
    char *combined = calloc(capacity, 1);
    if (combined == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (true) {
        char input1[257];
        if (scanf("%256s", input1) != 1 || input1[0] == '#') {
            break;
        }
        size += strlen(input1);
        if (size >= capacity) {
            char *tmp = realloc(combined, capacity *= 2);
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                free(combined);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            combined = tmp;
        }
        strcat(combined, input1);
    }
    printf("%s", combined);
    free(combined);
    return 0;
}
```

## Uncalled-for optimization

David C. Rankin pointed out another important thing to take care of when using library functions, that is not to assume they are O(1). Repeatedly calling `strcat()` is not the smartest move, since it's always scanning from the beginning. So here I replaced the `strcat()` with a ligher `strcpy()`, storing the length of the string, before adding the new one.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t capacity = 257, size = 0;
    char *combined = calloc(capacity, 1);
    if (combined == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (true) {
        char input1[257];
        if (scanf("%256s", input1) != 1 || input1[0] == '#') {
            break;
        }
        size_t oldsize = size;
        size += strlen(input1);
        if (size >= capacity) {
            char *tmp = realloc(combined, capacity *= 2);
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                free(combined);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            combined = tmp;
        }
        strcpy(combined + oldsize, input1);
    }
    printf("%s", combined);
    free(combined);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only suggestion would be to replace `strcat()` with `strcpy (combined + offset, ...)`. Since you already know how many character are contained in combined, just copy the new string at that offset. Otherwise, you have to re-scan the whole string for `strcat()` to locate the nul-terminating character each time. The well-formatted answer and the good effort for the explanation are worthy of the vote.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Top suggestion! Incorporated in the edit. This also allowed me to fix an "I'll make this change only for debug" bug: I set the initial capacity to 2, just to check if the `realloc` stuff was working, but it should have been initially at least the size of the largest string plus the terminator. Thanks.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you. [There are 2 hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-1 errors.](https://twitter.com/secretGeek/status/7269997868?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E7269997868%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmartinfowler.com%2Fbliki%2FTwoHardThings.html). Fixed.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana There are 2 types of people: those who can deduce an answer from incomplete facts. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, your idea that `strcpy()` will copy only up to the allocated memory is incorrect. `strcpy()` will copy beyond the allocated memory which is the reason it is unsafe and maybe the reason for the *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*.

`strcpy()` in your code copies all characters from `input1` to `combined` but as the size of `combined` is less than `input1` thus problem occurs.

Instead, you should use `strncpy()` to copy only n number of characters to avoid writing to memory beyond the allocated space.

You should also make sure that `combined` is ended with '\0' properly.

And `combined[0]='\0'` will not initialize all the allocated memory with '\0', this only assigned '\0' to the first byte. To initialize all the allocated memory to '\0' you need to use `memset()` after `malloc()`

```
combined = malloc(sizeof(char)*(input1_index+1+1));
combined[0] = '\0'; //use memset() here
strcpy(combined,input1); //Try using strncpy(combined, input1, input1_index) here
```